# My SQL Query - Get items that had there prices reduced in the last 30 days

Tags: mysql

I have a table that keeps track of inventory price updates.

```
CREATE TABLE pricechangelog (
    id int,
    SKU varchar(50),
    oldSelling DOUBLE(22,2),
    newSelling DOUBLE(22,2),
    date DATETIME
);
```

I would like to get the items that had their price reduced overrall in the last 30 days,
how would I go about doing that

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help us understand enough to be able to answer this. With just a table definition we are blind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This could be possible by find the difference of the current timestamp and the date. DATEDIFF() Function, and the newselling value shuould be less than the oldselling

```
SELECT * 
FROM pricechangelog 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, date)<= 30 
AND oldSelling>newSelling;
```